# SQL query is empty in left join

Tags: sql

I have a table with profiles holding information on accounts on my site. It's possible to promote a profile on different pages ex. search page and frontpage until an expire date.

Promotions is stored in the table profile_promo and joined by profile_id.

My problem is that on the search page I want to show all profiles and left join with the promotion table

```
LEFT JOIN profile_promotion pp ON pp.profile_id = profile.id 
WHERE (pp.page = 'search' OR pp.page is NULL) and pp.expire >= now()
```

This works fine as long as there is a promotion on the search page or if there is no promotions at all.

If there is only a promotion on the frontpage I don’t get any results at all for my search page because of the WHERE.

But I still want the information from the profile regardless if there are promotions or not.
Due note, that a profile can have promotion on multiple pages at the same time (maybe that changes some logic)

I’m not good at SQL so how do I solve this?

Comment: Move the conditions of the WHERE clause to the ON clause.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using where clause with LEFT JOIN converts it to INNER JOIN ultimately. You need to adjust your conditions as -

```
LEFT JOIN profile_promotion pp ON pp.profile_id = profile.id 
                               AND (pp.page = 'search' OR pp.page is NULL)
                               AND pp.expire >= now()
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. but it does not look like i need the "OR pp.page is NULL" :)

Comment: You may remove that condition then.

Answer (score 0):

As you now know the correct logic for matching non-expired, "search" promotions is:

```
FROM profile p LEFT JOIN
     profile_promotion pp
     ON pp.profile_id = p.id  AND
        pp.page = 'search' AND
        pp.expire >= now()
```

The logic of a `LEFT JOIN` is that it returns all rows in the first table, even when the `ON` conditions evaluate to `NULL`.

For this reason, filtering conditions *on the second* table should be in the `ON` clause.  Filtering conditions on the *first* table only should be in the `WHERE` clause.

Your code:

```
FROM profile p LEFT JOIN
     profile_promotion pp
     ON pp.profile_id = p.id  AND
WHERE (pp.page = 'search' OR pp.page is NULL) AND
      pp.expire >= now()
```

Turns this into an `INNER JOIN`, because of the second condition.  When the `LEFT JOIN` does not find a match, then `pp.expire` will be `NULL` and fail the condition.

You could try to get around that by doing:

```
WHERE (pp.page = 'search' OR pp.page is NULL) AND
      (pp.expire >= now() OR pp.expire IS NULL)
```

However, this is still not the same logic.  This will catch when there is no match in `pp` at all.  However, it will not do what you want when there is a match, but not for `search`.